# Read coordinates of 4 points. Do they make a square?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I calculate the distance between the points and if the distances are equal the point make a square, else no. My code works only if I read the coordinates in the following order A(x, y), B(x, y), C(x, y), D(x, y) or reverse. But if I read like this for example A(x, y), B(x, y),  D(x, y), C(x, y) it won't work because the dist method will calculate the square's diagonal length. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}a[10];

int dist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int c1, c2;
    c1 = x2-x1;
    c2 = y2-y1;
    return (c1*c1)+(c2*c2);
}

int main()
{
    int d1, d2, d3, d4;
    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
    {
        cout << 'X' << i << '='; cin >> a[i].x;
        cout << 'Y' << i << '='; cin >> a[i].y;
    }
    d1 = dist(a[1].x, a[1].y, a[2].x, a[2].y);
    d2 = dist(a[2].x, a[2].y, a[3].x, a[3].y);
    d3 = dist(a[3].x, a[3].y, a[4].x, a[4].y);
    d4 = dist(a[4].x, a[4].y, a[1].x, a[1].y);
    if(d1==d2 && d1==d3 && d1==d4)
        cout << "Is a square";
    else
        cout << "Is not a square";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the distances are equal, you've got a rhombus, not necessarily a square :)

Comment: You should check for angles/diagonals as well. Each of the four points should have two lines perpendicular to each other of the same length, and one diagonal of length `sqrt(2*x*x)`.

Comment: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/101/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking the distances is not enough, you'll need to check at least an angle, as the shape could be a rhombus.

Checking only angles is also not enough, because you could end up with a rectangle.

There are a total of 6 distances between the points. Calculate all of them. Out of those 6, four should be equal (call their length `x`). - **this guarantees a rhombus**

The other two should be equal between themselves (call their length `y`). **this guarantees a rectangle**

Put a rhombus and a rectangle together and **BAM!** - square.

Comment: Cool, but one more thing: You assumed that the shape is convex. The OP has problems when the shape is concave, like `▶◀`, and this won't suffice. You need to take the order into consideration too.

Comment: @Kos actually, that shape wouldn't pass the first requirement.

Comment: I can't agree. Checking distances with no respect to their order treats the shape as a set of 4 corner points, which makes `▶◀` and a rectangle indistinguishable. Vertex order is necessary to distinguish the two.

Comment: @Kos I think he meant 'check at least an angle' as the first requirement (although a dot-product might be easier)

Comment: @Kos I disagree. It doesn't matter if that shape is a rectangle or not. It's not a square.

Comment: @Kos the distances are not equal for your shape. If they were, they'd form a square. Note that the coloring is not essential here.

Comment: @Leonardo all **6** can't be the same.

Comment: @Leonardo if they're all the same, you have six zeroes

Comment: @Kos actually you dont need to take the order of the points in considerations as long you dont measure a distance twice (measure A to B and after you measure B to A)

Comment: But it isn't a rectangle, but it satisfies your distance-based rectangle test.

Comment: @Kos It actually is a rectangle. You have 4 points there. That's it. There are no lines connecting them, just 4 points. If you remove the hashing and the points from your drawing, you'll end up with a rectangle.

Comment: It isn't. Rectangle is one set of points, and the quadrilateral I mentioned is a different set of points, even though they may have the same corners and share two sides.

Comment: @Kos the input to the op's question is an unordered set of points. Ergo the problem in the first paragraph, when the order in which the points are introduced affects the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it with only angles using inner products. Each vertex A should have two other vertices B and C such that AB and AC are at a right angle (0 inner product) as well as one vertex D such that AB and AD as well AC and AD are both at exactly 45 degrees (normalized dot product = acos(45 degrees), i.e. ~ 0.6675). If that is true for all four vertices you have a square.

Answer (score 2):

Choose one vertex of the square (without loss of generality say A) and consider this the origin. Get 3 vectors formed from the origin to each other corner (AB, AC, AD). Vectorially these are given by B-A, C-A and D-A. Calculate the inner product of each vector with the other. If the vertices form a rectangle, one inner product will be zero (the perpendicular edge vectors). If they form a square then the other 2 inner products also must be equal to each other due to the common angle of 45 degrees between them. Thus if one inner product is zero and the other 2 are equal to eachother and the 4 distances are the same you have a square.

Answer (score 0):

With four points, you have a total of six distances. If you compute the distance squared (which is easier, of course), then for any pair of edges with length L1, L2, the following is true

```
L1 == L2 || 2*L1 == L2 || L1 = 2*L2
```

You can create the following piece of code to implement this:

```
int isSquare (point *p1, point *p2, point *p3, point *p4) {
double dx, dy;
double dd[6];
point *pp[4];

pp[0]=p1; pp[1]=p2; pp[2]=p3; pp[3]=p4;
int ii, jj, kk, nn;
kk = 0;
// loop over all combinations of first and second point
// six in all
for(ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
  for(jj=ii+1; jj<4; jj++) {
    dx = pp[ii]->x - pp[jj]->x;
    dy = pp[ii]->y - pp[jj]->y;
    dd[kk]= dx*dx + dy*dy;
    if (dd[kk]==0) return 0; // two identical points: not a square
    if(kk>1) {
      for(nn= 0; nn < kk-1; nn++) {
        // if both are "sides", we expect their length to be the same;
        // if one is a diagonal and the other a side, their ratio is 2
        // since we are working with the square of the number
        if (!(((2*dd[nn] == dd[kk] ) || \
               (dd[nn] == dd[kk])    || \
               (2*dd[kk] == dd[nn] )))) return 0;
      }
    }
     kk++;
  }
}
return 1; // got here: all combinations tested OK, we have a square

}
```