# C++ Detecting Squares

Tags: c++

I built the following code to read 4 pairs of coordinates to calculate if it's a square or not:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}a[10];

int dist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
// function to compute the (square of the) distance between two points
    int c1, c2;
    c1 = x2-x1;
    c2 = y2-y1;
    return (c1*c1)+(c2*c2);
}

int main()
{
    int d1, d2, d3, d4;
    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
    {
        cout << 'X' << i << '='; cin >> a[i].x;
        cout << 'Y' << i << '='; cin >> a[i].y;
    }
    d1 = dist(a[1].x, a[1].y, a[2].x, a[2].y);
    d2 = dist(a[2].x, a[2].y, a[3].x, a[3].y);
    d3 = dist(a[3].x, a[3].y, a[4].x, a[4].y);
    d4 = dist(a[4].x, a[4].y, a[1].x, a[1].y);
    if(d1==d2 && d1==d3 && d1==d4)
        cout << "Is a square";
    else
        cout << "Is not a square";
    return 0;
}
```

The code works well enough, but I want to read multiple coordinates (more than four) and check every possible combination of four points to see if they make a square.

I can't figure out how to extend the method above to work with more than four points as input (and selecting all combination of four from that); can anyone give me a hint/hand please?

Comment: Array starts from `0` not `1`.

Comment: The `dist` function is kind of misleading. I wouldn't expect it to give the square. Also, what if I was to input the top left, top right, bottom left, then bottom right? Your program would incorrectly say it isn't a square.

Comment: When you say you want to make an automated system, what do you mean by that? How do you want to provide input, how do you expect the output? Typically you'd use command line arguments to provide input, and then use `cout` to output your result, then another program can read it from there. You could also write your result to a file. If you just want to be able to do the calculation more times, you could use a loop.

Comment: @chris I agree, they need to at least take the `sqrt` of that before returning if they are trying to do `sqrt(dX^2 + dY^2)`

Comment: Are you saying "given N (x,y) pairs, select all possible combinations of 4 to find combinations that form a square"?

Comment: @Cyber, Alternatively, one could use `std::hypot`.

Comment: @Cyber: If the nos are equal, it implies the square are equal too. SO, his function is right.

Comment: @Cyber: sqrt should really be avoided if possible because it is a costly operation. Better compare square of distance and rename the function.

Comment: Exaclty  Floris thats what I want xD

Comment: @user127979, Then as a naive approach, your problem can be simplified to "How do I pick out all subsets of cardinality M from a set of cardinality N?"

Comment: For example I want to improve my system to read multiple pairs.
Example input:
9->
->5 3
->1 4
->1 3
->1 2
->2 1
->2 3
->3 4
->3 2
->4 2

 Output should be: 3 squares possible

Comment: I think OP want to solve the same issue than [algorithm-detecting-squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267401/algorithm-detecting-squares), but does provide code :-)

Comment: Jarod42 Yes its true. nobody wants to help me :|

Comment: I would do in an other way, for each couple of points, check if the the 2 next points of a direct square are present.

Comment: @user127979 if you can reword the question so it can be re-opened, I have some code to post that solves your problem...

Comment: I have edited the question to make clear what OP is after - based on the comments. I believe it is now answerable (and in fact I have an answer ready to post if this is re-opened...)

Comment: By the way - you say "I built the following code". I found 90% of this code in another question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10786089/1967396 . This may not be where you got it from; it just suggests that this code existed "on the internet" and is not just your own creation. It is considered good practice to acknowledge that...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a complete-graph problem. Since all points are int's, one thing I can think of is doing a depth-first search, without duplicates, with the distance^2 as the weight. And you sorta need a dual-pseudograph to keep the angle info (a boolean suffices for right-angle v.s. non-right-angle).

Start from a point 0 , step to the nearest neighbor 1, and then, start from the neighbor 1, find its neighbors 2,3,4 ..., and filter on two criteria: distance and angle. Each depth-first search needs only 4 steps max, since there are only 4 sides.

Iterate through all points, and book-keeping visited points, you may track how many squares made during the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that checks all combinations of four points to see if they are square. Note that your original method for testing "square" was faulty - first, even if points were given in the correct order, a diamond shape would (wrongly) be called "square"; second, if points were given in the "wrong" order, a square might not look square.

I fixed both those issues. Also, I created a simple nested loop that generates all possible combinations of four points and tests them; this can be made much more efficient (for example, if points 1,2 and 3 do not form a "isosceles right triangle" there is no point to test the fourth point - so you can save a lot of time by not testing for all other possible points). I will leave that for another time.

I did not bother writing the "input N points" part of the code - I don't think that is what you were struggling with. Let me know if I was wrong to assume that.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct{
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

int isSquare (point *p1, point *p2, point *p3, point *p4) {
double dx, dy;
double dd[6];
point *pp[4];

pp[0]=p1; pp[1]=p2; pp[2]=p3; pp[3]=p4;
int ii, jj, kk, nn;
kk = 0;
// loop over all combinations of first and second point
// six in all
for(ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
  for(jj=ii+1; jj<4; jj++) {
    dx = pp[ii]->x - pp[jj]->x;
    dy = pp[ii]->y - pp[jj]->y;
    dd[kk]= dx*dx + dy*dy;
    if (dd[kk]==0) return 0; // two identical points: not a square
    if(kk>1) {
      for(nn= 0; nn < kk-1; nn++) {
        // if both are "sides", we expect their length to be the same;
        // if one is a diagonal and the other a side, their ratio is 2
        // since we are working with the square of the number
        if (!(((2*dd[nn] == dd[kk] ) || (dd[nn] == dd[kk]) || 2*dd[kk] == dd[nn] ))) return 0;
      }
    }
     kk++;
  }
}
return 1; // got here: all combinations tested OK, we have a square

}

int main(void) {
  // pick ten numbers - chosen so there are two squares
  point p[10]={{1,2},{3,2},{1,4},{7,8},{2,4},{3,4},{6,7},{8,7},{2,5},{3,5}};
  double d2[10][10];
  int ii, jj, kk, ll;
  // loop over all possible combinations: 
  // since there are just four to pick we can hard-wire the loop
  for(ii=0; ii<7; ii++) {
    for(jj = ii+1; jj<8; jj++) {
      for(kk = jj+1; kk<9; kk++) {
        for(ll = kk+1; ll<10; ll++) {
          if(isSquare(p+ii, p+jj, p+kk, p+ll)) {
            std::cout << "combination: " << ii << "," << jj << "," << kk << "," << ll << " is a square\n";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
combination: 0,1,2,5 is a square
combination: 4,5,8,9 is a square
```